# Use of Macro Expansion

Tags: c++, macros

Can anyone Explain what exactly is the use of the Macro Expansion In C or C++ Program.

```
# define UPPER 3
main()
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<UPPER;++i)
cout<<i;
}
```

The same thing could be achieved using constants and making there scope global, then why do we use it, are they used just to increase the readability of the program?

Comment: I prefer `enum { UPPER = 3; }`. avoid macro if you can

Comment: Macros are useful for many things, but that isn't a good example.

Comment: It has no benefit in the above case than `const int UPPER = 3;` but in some cases macros can be beneficial. With `#define PR(x) (cout << #x " = " << x)`, you can use `PR(i)` instead of `cout << i`.